# how to add label using j2html

Tags: java, html, j2html

I am trying to create a login form with j2html,but when try adding label in my form,there is no predefined label exists e.g withId(),withName()

```
 private static Tag generateUserField(String user) {
        return input().withType("text").withName("user").withId(user).withPlaceholder("Enter username");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<label>` is a separate element, it's **not** a part of the `<input>`. So you need to generate it separately via [`TagCreator.label()`](https://jar-download.com/javaDoc/com.j2html/j2html/1.3.0/j2html/TagCreator.html#label--).